# What is the word for the high-pitched "sex sound" a woman makes?

Tags: single-word-requests

The other day I was texting someone and I was talking about Buffy the Vampire Slayer. I wanted to say it's cute when she makes that [high-pitched sex sound a woman makes] sound when she's fighting. And I just couldn't find the right word to use that made sense.

It's easy to make the sound, and everyone knows what it is. Is there really not a word that accurately describes it? It's not a moan or a groan as far as I understand those words.

Here's an example: http://www.soundsnap.com/node/45537 (WARNING: these are sex sounds and NSFW. It's just audio, no pictures.)

The sound I'm referring to is the second and third one she makes (maybe just a little shorter than her examples).

Comment: See also: professional ladies' tennis

Comment: @AndrewVit: Have you been watching 'Ken Park'? :)

Comment: Is is *shriek* you're looking for?

Comment: @Autoresponder Shriek sounds scary. Not really a good fit.

Comment: Why looking for an unique word ? If you have had a sufficient number of partners, you should know that some just sigh, others yell, with all possible intermediates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a tricky one to come up with one apt word without getting into various connotations:

- A **moan** is a low sound, generally.
- A **whimper** sounds plaintive or submissive.
- A **grunt** or a **groan** doesn't sound ladylike.
- A **squeal** sounds too drawn out.

I would be surprised if there's actually a definitive word for it. To describe the sound in that context, I might say **squeak**, which is a sort of cute sound.

Comment: A _moan_ is a low sound if there's no sexual context, but in the context of sex, I've always heard the noise the OP linked to called a _moan_. However, that might make it confusing to use the word _moan_ when describing the Buffy example.

I've also (relatively commonly) heard such sounds called _sex noises_ (not _sounds_), which might actually be your best bet here: "It's cute when she makes sex noises while she's fighting."

Comment: I like whimper and I hadn't thought of that. It's not an exact fit, but pretty close. Maybe "short whimper sound" or "high whimper sound" works best in the Buffy example. I found this example of whimper on that same site: http://www.soundsnap.com/node/110906. I'm surprised there isn't a more universally understood word for such a common sound.

Comment: This is the way the sex ends: This is the way the sex ends: This is the way the sex ends: Not with a bang, but a whimper.

Answer (score 7):

*Thrifty Shades of Grey* by Mari-Lou A #1

- First, she emitted ***squeals*** of delight.
- Then, lustily, she moaned her "***oohs***" and "**ahhs**".
- Finally, she heaved an ecstatic ***"sigh"***.

<sub>(I know, it doesn't answer the question. But I just couldn't resist myself!)</sub>

Comment: *Thrifty* Shades of Grey is the wholesale version?

Answer (score 4):

The word I would use to describe such a sound is **orgasmic**. Women sometimes make such sounds in "unusual" places, such as dance floors. Or in Buffy's case, while fighting.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I've heard these referred to as *moans of pleasure*, but it seems we're in search of a single word here.

Perhaps the most accurate word would be a ***cry***, as grunts/groans/moans are generally more low-pitched and protracted than the sound in question. *Cry* also has the benefit of covering many different varieties of such utterances.

Though not typically used in this context, a think the noun ***crow*** would also be applicable. (One [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crow) for crow is "an inarticulate cry of pleasure".)

Ultimately, however, the word depends on the woman. In my experience, some tend to [yelp](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yelp) ("a quick, sharp, shrill cry, as a dog or fox"), others [squawk](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/squawk) ("a loud, harsh cry, as a duck or other fowl when frightened"), and still others [whoop](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whoop) ("a loud cry or shout in expressing enthusiasm, excitement").

Comment: Yelp is one I considered, it just sounds more dog like.

Comment: I've heard "cries out" used to describe sex, but not really to make a sound. That would be more for saying something during sex.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the word ***scream*** to other words that apply far more commonly to unsexual yelps of a feline or a hircine nature.

What's more it makes for a stiff luscious cocktail: [***screaming orgasm***](http://www.drinksmixer.com/drink1817.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @AndrewVit put it, the connotation can be rather different. Here are some synonyms from the 'Concise Oxford Thesaurus', not sure which one you might actually use...

**squeak** - peep, cheep, pipe, piping, squeal, tweet, yelp, whimper

Comment: I don't think women *tweet* while they're in bed...

Comment: Squeal and whimper are pretty good. Squeal seems pig-like to me, though.

Comment: @Mahnax: I agree. :) I listed *all* the synonyms from the dictionary under **squeak**.

Comment: @Mahnax Depends if she brings her mobile phone along.